# How to export Fortigate firmware image from Fortigate device (switch)?

Tags: reverse-engineering, firmware, fortigate, forticlient

I recenlty acquired a fortigate 100D switch (firmware version 6.0.9) and i am trying to extract the firmware image or executable from it. I don't have a fortinet account with valid subscription so i can't download the image from the site.

i tried [this](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16325/how-to-unpack-the-fortigate-firmware?newreg=66d9397ed29c4614abec70fd16c03b87) and specifically Igor's answer (`fnsysctl cp /bin/init /var/log/root/mlog.0`) but no luck, `cp` command is not recognized in FortiOS. I also tried using `scp` with `ssh` login and i managed to export the configuration file to my pc (ex. `scp admin@192.168.10.14:sys_config C:\Users\...`), but when i try to export the firmware image and replace [sys_config] with [fgt-image] then i get (501 permission denied) error.

Has anyone managed this, any suggestions?